python3.11 Aead anonymization Pickle serializer error
I am doing a program to anonymize some columns on a dataframe using the tink library to do it, but I am getting a serialize error in daead object in an udf that I had wrote
I rewrite all the program to remove the class and have only the udf with the lambda but I got the same error

def readKeyDaead(params):
    
    try:
        # Get params
        keyset_file = params["keyset_file"]
        
        # Initialize DAEAD
        daead.register()
        
        # Reads JSON keyset
        with open(keyset_file, 'r') as json_file:
            json_keyset = json.load(json_file)
        
        # Generate keyset_handle
        keyset_handle = tink.json_proto_keyset_format.parse(json_keyset, secret_key_access.TOKEN)
        
        # Generates primitive
        daead_primitive = keyset_handle.primitive(daead.DeterministicAead)
        
        # End of function
        return daead_primitive
        
    
    except Exception as error:
        print("ERROR: " + str(error))

@dataclass
class EncryptDaead:
    primitive = ""
    associated_data= ""

    def __init__(self, primitive=None, associated_data=None):
        self.primitive = primitive or self.primitive
        self.associated_data = associated_data or self.associated_data
     
    def apply(self, df: DataFrame, column: str) -> DataFrame:
        primitive = self.primitive
        associated_data = self.associated_data

        def encrypt(data: str) -> str:
            try:                    
                # Encrypt Data
                ciphertext = primitive.encrypt_deterministically(data.encode('utf-8'), associated_data.encode('utf-8'))
                ciphertext_base64 = b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')

                # End of function   
                return ciphertext_base64
                
            except Exception as error:
                print("ERROR: " + str(error))

        df = df.withColumn("is_stop_word", udf(encrypt)(column))
        return df

def encryptColumnDaead(params, spark):
    
    try:
        # Get params
        df = params["df"]
        column = params["column"]
        enc_type = params["enc_type"]
        primitive = params["primitive"]
        associated_data = params["associated_data"]

        type_ok = 0
        # Encript column
            encrypter = EncryptDaead(primitive = primitive, associated_data = associated_data)
            df = encrypter.apply(df, column)

            type_ok = 1

        # End of function   
        
    except Exception as error:
        print("ERROR: " + str(error))


And the error that I am getting when I run the program, in a unix machine, with python3.11 xxx.py cmd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/SP/dat/App/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 459, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/SP/dat/App/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/var/SP/dat/App/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 632, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle 'tink.cc.pybind.tink_bindings.DeterministicAead' object
ERROR: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle 'tink.cc.pybind.tink_bindings.DeterministicAead' object
ERROR: [PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS] Path file:/var/SP/dat/ntsc_rend_cyph/ES.NS.SUBSCRIBERUSERPLANE.070320242000078.snappy.parquet already exists. Set mode as "overwrite" to overwrite the existing path.


I tried to rewrite the udf without the class but I got the same error

Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like the error you pasted does not match the code. Please update your question (not here in the comments) to show how you call your code and what is the error message you get in that context.
